# Why the "Estimated age range" in Waikato Radiocarbon Dating Laboratory form?

Tags: radioactivity

During a discussion with a creationist he pointed to the "Estimated age range:"  in the form
https://radiocarbondating.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0007/405556/Sample-Submission-Form-2020.pdf.

Quote:

> The truth is the labs begins by asking the researcher what age they expect prior to the testing as to “calibrate” the data results to meet that expectation (circular reasoning).

My utterly inexpert guesses:

- There are lots of options. Some options are unapplicable/give less reliable results in some age ranges. The researcher (archeologist/paleontologist/...) can be unaware of this.
- Older samples require more test time to get the same level of confidence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating#Errors_and_reliability).

Another possibilities?

Comment: I don’t see any physics question here. Arguing with creationists will get you nowhere, regardless of actual facts.

Comment: @JonCuster: (1) Why  the "Estimated age range:" is required? (2) I disagree. Creationism is a real danger for science.

Comment: The test used (chemical, or accelerator) will prsumably depend on how much $^{14}$C is to be expected. If out of the test range you will not get a reading  at all, and you will have wasted the money your paid for the test.

Comment: @mikestone, thanks. I understand than my two guesses are essentially right.